# Super long loop stuck in javascript after 8 words

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Ok so i have this code that is taking a super long time to compile. when it hits the loop that is where it breaks. how can i fix this??

http://jsfiddle.net/HTzUt/2/

Thanks in advance.

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitAT.length; i++)
{
    if ( splitAT[i] !== prev )
    {
        splitAT.push(splitAT[i]);
        wordCount.push(1);
    } 
    else 
    {
        wordCount[wordCount.length-1]++;
    }
    prev = splitAT[i];
 }

return [splitAT, wordCount];



document.write('[' + result[0] + ']<br>[' + result[1] + ']')
```

Comment: Stop modifying the bounds of the array from within the loop in which you iterate over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitAT.length; i++)
{
    if ( splitAT[i] !== prev )
    {
        splitAT.push(splitAT[i]);
...
```

You're (potentially) increasing the length of the array that you're iterating over.  `push` will add an extra item to the array and increase the length.  This will cause the loop to run for a long time or potentially forever depending on how the data is structured